# prevent element from being removed if mouse overed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have notifications that appear in the top left part of the screen. They are on a 5 second delay and than get removed. If a user is hovered over one it should get removed.

here is my jquery code

```
$alert.on('mouseover', function() {
    clearTimeout(growl_remove);
});
growl_remove = setTimeout(function() {
    return $alert.alert("close");
}, 5000);
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="growl col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 alert alert-danger" style="position: fixed; margin: 0px; z-index: 9999; top: 26.846393585205078px; right: 20px;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp;Invalid Username or Passowrd
</div>
```

Now this does seem to work, but it stops the very last alert from being removed not the one with the mouse over it.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KU5gy/

Comment: Sounds like a closure problem. Please share the HTML and maybe put together a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Could it help?

```
var AlertController = function(){
  var _timeoutId = null;
  var _resetTimeout = function() {
    clearTimeour(_timeoutId);
    _timeoutId = setTimeout(function() { $alert.alert("close"); }, 5000);
  }
  var _init(){
      $alert.on('mouseover', resetTimeout);
  }
  return {
      showNotification: function(){
        $alert.alert("show");
        _init();
      }
  }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
//call it when your notification is to be shown
function onNotification(){
  new AlertController().showNotification();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`  on the line `var _init(){`

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh: I have not tested the code. But the line that gives the error probably should be `var _init = function() {  $alert.on(....)} `

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to solve my problems

```
var bootstrap_growl_remove = [];

$alert.on('mouseover', function() {
  clearTimeout(bootstrap_growl_remove[$alert.index()]);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  bootstrap_growl_remove[$alert.index()] = setTimeout(function() {
    return $alert.alert("close");
  }, options.delay);
});

bootstrap_growl_remove[$alert.index()] = setTimeout(function() {
  return $alert.alert("close");
}, options.delay);
```